# Removing units from an R vector

Tags: r

Using the `units` package I can create a vector with physical units, for example:

```
library(units)
a = 1:10
units(a) <- with(ud_units, m/s) 
a
## Units: m/s
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

but how do I get back to a plain R vector without units?

`unclass(a)` does most of the work, but leaves a bunch of attributes in the vector:

```
unclass(a)
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
## attr(,"units")
## $numerator
## [1] "m"
##
## $denominator
## [1] "s"
##
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "symbolic_units"
```

but I feel there should be a simpler way. Assigning as `unitless` doesn't help, it creates a vector with "unitless" units.

Nothing in the vignette either...

Comment: `as.vector(a)`?

Comment: Linking also this: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/function-to-remove-attributes-td914615.html

So an alternative is `attributes(a) = NULL`, though `?as.vector` suggests it's pretty specifically for this purpose

Comment: `as.integer` should also do

Comment: I looked around a bit for a canonical "How to remove attributes Q" and couldn't find one, though I myself have had this question before (not sure if/how I resolved).

Comment: The first person to put `as.vector` as an answer gets the points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `as.vector`

or to be more general :

```
clean_units <- function(x){
  attr(x,"units") <- NULL
  class(x) <- setdiff(class(x),"units")
  x
}

a <- clean_units(a)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
str(a)
# int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 3):

`as.vector` should work in this case:

```r
library(units)                 
a = 1:10                       
units(a) <- with(ud_units, m/s)
a                              
#> Units: m/s
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
str(a)                         
#> Class 'units'  atomic [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..- attr(*, "units")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ numerator  : chr "m"
#>   .. ..$ denominator: chr "s"
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "symbolic_units"

b = as.vector(a)               
str(b)                         
#>  int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that nowadays there is the `drop_units` function making this much easier and more intuitive:

```r
library(units)
#> udunits database from /usr/share/xml/udunits/udunits2.xml
a = set_units(1:10,'m/s')
a
#> Units: [m/s]
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
drop_units(a)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I guess `as.vector` can be made to work with matrices too

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
m = set_units(matrix(rnorm(4), 2), m/s)
m
#Units: m/s
#           [,1]      [,2]
#[1,]  1.3709584 0.3631284
#[2,] -0.5646982 0.6328626

class(m)
#[1] "units"

foo = function(x){
    y = as.vector(x)
    dim(y) = dim(x)
    return(y)
}

foo(m)
#           [,1]      [,2]
#[1,]  1.3709584 0.3631284
#[2,] -0.5646982 0.6328626

class(foo(m))
#[1] "matrix"

foo(a)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

class(foo(a))
#[1] "integer"
```

Comment: The problem is that it strips off the object of its attributes that may have been added before or after unit conversion, and of potential additional classes, that can't be added before conversion (`set_units` doesn't like it) but may be added afterwards.